# html page keeps refreshing

Tags: php, html

This is my code for an admin login page but the page keeps refreshing instead of redirecting. I have looked at many articles but I couldn't solve the issue

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Admin Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <h2>Admin Login</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="admin" name="admin">
            <?PHP
                ob_start();
                $admin = ['admin'];
                if ($admin == "1234") {
                    header("Location: admin.php", true, 301 );
                    die();
                    exit();
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button><br>
        </div>
    
        <p>
        Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a><br><br>
        Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am open for suggestions!

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, please go and do that first of all now. Unless you had outbut buffering enabled by default, this should give you a warning, that it can't send a header at this point, because there was already output created.

Comment: There is no good reason to have the PHP code nested in there in that position to begin with - you should move this to the top of the document. Try and follow the [input–process–output (IPO) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model) when writing such things.

Comment: But `$admin = ['admin']; if ($admin == "1234")` really makes little sense. There is no way that variable could ever change its value between those two statements, so that the if condition would become true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the intent of your code, I think you intend to get the POST value of the admin field in this line:

```
$admin = ['admin'];
```

To get form fields sent in a POST, you need to use:

```
$admin = $_POST['admin'];
```

You can also...

1. Move the whole PHP code block to the top of the file, as it doesn't need to be after the HTML input (when you submit the form it will round-trip back to the server).
2. Remove the `die()` from your [redirect code](https://perishablepress.com/permanent-301-redirect-via-php-or-htaccess/)
3. Start looking into [security](https://abcphp.net/php-login-page/) a bit as your login form is very much like the first login form we all write - but there are problems doing things this way - if this is just your first go it's not a big deal, but don't have anything exposed to the world with authorisation code like this

Comment: It worked after I added 'post', thank you.